# How to make interface for toast message in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to make interface with some method like showToast() which I will implement in ,multiple class where needed.How can I make that

code:-

```
public interface Test {
void showToast();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use my snippet.
First make a method in any Util/Helper class.

```
    public static void toastOnMain(final String message, final int toastLength) {
    if (context == null) {
        return;
    }

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(context, message, toastLength).show();
        }
    });
}
```

And then call

```
Classname.toastOnMain("Hello World");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface Logger{
      public static void shortToast(Context ctx,String msg){
           Toast.makeText(ctx,msg,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

      public static void longToast(Context ctx,String msg){
           Toast.makeText(ctx,msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
}
```

Use it like this...

```
Logger.shortToast(this,"HELLO");
```